# if statement echo out different links for different codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using this code

HTML:

```
<div id="message">some message</div>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />​
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("#message").hide();
$("#fail").hide();

var prefix = ['HX', 'HD', 'BD', 'LS']

$('#myInput').keyup(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var firstTwo = value.substr(0,2);
    var firstTwoUpper = firstTwo.toUpperCase();

    if(firstTwo != firstTwoUpper) {
        $(this).val( value.replace(/^\w\w/, firstTwoUpper) );
    }
    if(value.length > 1) {
        if($.inArray(firstTwoUpper, prefix) >= 0) {
            $("#fail").hide();
            $("#message:hidden").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#message").hide();
            $("#fail:hidden").fadeIn();
        }
    } else {
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#fail").hide();
    }
 });
});
```

​
To be a post code check.  I got the above code from      here:    [Jquery check array perform function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896418/jquery-check-array-perform-function/24780023#24780023) and it works just fine but I want to display a message containing a link which all differ from one another. For example I want code 'HX' to link to facebook and I want 'BD' to link to the BBC.  How would I write the if statement correctly? I have tried various ways but I am not achieving what I need.

Could someone give me a little guideance please?

Thanks,

Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QyzF5/6/) does what you might be looking for

```
<div id="message"><a href="#">Some link</a></div>
<div id="fail">Invalid postcode</div>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />

$(function () {
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#fail").hide();

    var prefix = ['HX', 'HD', 'BD', 'LS'];
    var links = ['http://www.facebook.com','http://www.example.com','http://www.bbc.com','#'];

    $('#myInput').keyup(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var firstTwo = value.substr(0, 2);
        var firstTwoUpper = firstTwo.toUpperCase();

        if (firstTwo != firstTwoUpper) {
            $(this).val(value.replace(/^\w\w/, firstTwoUpper));
        }
        if (value.length > 1) {
            var index = $.inArray(firstTwoUpper, prefix);
            if (index >= 0) {
                $("#fail").hide();
                $("#message").fadeIn();
                $("#message a").attr("href",links[index]).html(links[index])
            } else {
                $("#message").hide();
                $("#fail:hidden").fadeIn();
            }
        } else {
            $("#message").hide();
            $("#fail").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thank you for that yes that is what I am looking for but no when you put in an incorrect postcode the 'Fail Message' doesn't show up!  Thank so much for your help!

Comment: @user3502952 you didn't provide a fail element

Comment: @user3502952. Check update fiddle. You had not put in the html in your question

Comment: Thank you Nikhil - this is absolutely perfect just what I needed. I am currently studying Javascript and Jquery and pratice everyday. Thank you once again.

Comment: you may upvote/mark this as correct answer for future references and helping other users.

Comment: Hi Nikhil I have made this my answer!  Thank you again and have a great day.

Comment: Just another quick one with the links could we change the text to just say click here? If not do not worry! Thank you again to all :)

Comment: you can put the text in the `.html()`

Answer (score 1):

this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/um67M/2/

I changed prefix from an array of strings to an array of objects.

You're going to see an issue if users type really fast because of the speed of fadeIn().

```
$(function() {
$("#message").hide();
$("#fail").hide();

    var prefix = [{code:'HX',link:'www.facebook.com'}, {code:'BD',link:'www.bbc.com'}];

$('#myInput').keyup(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var firstTwo = value.substr(0,2);
    var firstTwoUpper = firstTwo.toUpperCase();

    if(firstTwo != firstTwoUpper) {
        $(this).val( value.replace(/^\w\w/, firstTwoUpper) );
    }
    if(value.length > 1) {
        for(var obj in prefix){
            console.log(firstTwoUpper, prefix[obj].code, firstTwoUpper == prefix[obj].code);
            if(firstTwoUpper === prefix[obj].code){
                 $("#fail").hide();
                var link = '<a href="'+prefix[obj].link+'">'+prefix[obj].link+'</a>';
                $("#message").append(link);
                $("#message:hidden").fadeIn();
                break;
            }else {
                $("#message").hide();
                $("#fail:hidden").fadeIn();
            }
        };
    } else {
        $("#message").empty();
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#fail").hide();
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for that! This is where I want to be going for this but the links are not clickable?! Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: ill make them actual links

Comment: Hi Dave, just want to say thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.  Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var firstTwo = value.substr(0, 2);
        var firstTwoUpper = firstTwo.toUpperCase();

        if (firstTwo != firstTwoUpper) {
            $(this).val(value.replace(/^\w\w/, firstTwoUpper));
        }
        if (value.length > 1) {
            if ($.inArray(firstTwoUpper, prefix) >= 0) {
                if (firstTwoUpper == "HX") {
                    $("#message").empty();
                    $("#message").html('<p>some message</p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
                } else if (firstTwoUpper == "HD") {

                    $("#message").empty();
                    $("#message").html('<p>other message</p><a `enter code here`href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack OverFlow</a>');
                }
                $("#fail").hide();
                $("#message:hidden").fadeIn();
            } else {
                $("#message").hide();
                $("#fail:hidden").fadeIn();
            }
        } else {
            $("#message").hide();
            $("#fail").hide();
        }
    });
```

the fiddle is here
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxh5b/)

Comment: Hi Roshan, thank you for this but I have found it doesn't work well when the user places an incorrect postcode.  Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: when user show incorrect post code it is showing fail message on top of the field , you can check it nicely. If you want different message you can change the text of fail message and write something else.

Comment: Hi Roshan, I can see that now! Thank you for your contributions  :)